# Consultas Sql Fallando en Python

Tags: python, mysql

estoy haciendo un ejercicio que se trata de consumir un api rest y luego esos datos mandarlos a una base de datos , el problema es que no se porque me tira error cuando creo que la consulta esta bien hecha, estoy usando Python y MySQL , seguramente tengo algún error en las consultas pero no lo puedo ver ! muchas gracias por su ayuda

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo :

```
import urllib.request
import json
import requests
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
db = pymysql.connect(autocommit=True,
                     host='localhost',
                     user='root',
                     password='',
                     database='tp2_mongo',
                     charset='utf8',
                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
print(db)

cursor = db.cursor()


def conexionUrl(id):

    url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/" + id

    # Consulta http
    resp = requests.get(url)

    if (resp.status_code != 404):

        # Lectura de json
        data = json.loads(resp.content)

        # Asignacion de datos
        codigoPais = data[0]['callingCodes'][0],
        nombrePais = data[0]['name'],
        capitalPais = data[0]['capital'],
        region = data[0]['region'],
        latitud = data[0]['latlng'][0],
        longitud = data[0]['latlng'][1],

        # print(codigoPais[0])
        # print("SELECT * FROM pais WHERE codigoPais = ?", codigoPais[0])
        pais = cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM pais WHERE codigoPais = ?", codigoPais[0])
        if(pais):
            cursor.execute('UPDATE pais SET nombrePais= ?,capitalPais=?,region=?,latitud=?,longitud=? WHERE codigoPais = ?',
                           nombrePais[0], capitalPais[0], region[0], latitud[0], longitud[0], codigoPais[0])
            db.close()
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO pais(codigoPais,nombrePais,capitalPais,region,latitud,longitud) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                           (codigoPais[0], nombrePais[0], capitalPais[0], region[0], latitud[0], longitud[0]))
            db.close()


for i in range(301):
    conexionUrl(str(i))
```

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro de que esta sea la solución ni puedo comprobarlo, pero prueba cambiar `"SELECT * FROM pais WHERE codigoPais = ?", codigoPais[0])` por `"SELECT * FROM pais WHERE codigoPais = ?", (codigoPais[0],))`. Notese que puse `codigoPais[0]` entre parentesis y con una coma delante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo conector que siga la [DP-API2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) ofrece información sobre cómo espera recibir los [parámetros](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

Parece que `pymysql` espera un `paramstyle = pyformat`, por lo que deberías cambiar tus *queries* para que acepte esta notación.

Por ejemplo:

```py
pais = cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM pais WHERE codigoPais = %s", codigoPais[0])
```